# Create string template and replace with contents of array

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have a string like so:

```
const m = 'Map<?,?>';
```

and an array like so:

```
const types = ['string', 'boolean'];
```

and I am looking to generate:

```
const r = 'Map<string,boolean>'
```

how can I do that? **Note** that I don't need to use a question mark in the template string, I can use a different character, maybe like this:

```
const m = 'Map<%s,%s>';
```

Also please **note** that I *cannot use ES6 template strings* of this nature `${}` because my template is not wrapped in a function.

I believe this will work in Node.js:

```
util.format(m, ...types);
```

but I guess what I am looking for is a way to use a question mark character (?) instead of using %s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest way is probably using a combination of [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Replace only replaces the first found position and reduce makes it easy to iterate over the given replacements.

```js
const m = 'Map<?,?>';

const types = ['string', 'boolean'];

const n = types.reduce((n, t) => n.replace('?', t), m);
console.log(n);
```

Or to formalize it into a function:

```
function format(str, key, replacements){
    return replacements.reduce((s, t) => s.replace(k, t), str);
}
```

Comment: probably a good idea to make a note on the comma operator, or explain that in the comments here. Oh just kidding, that's not a comma operator.

Comment: What do you mean by comma operator?

Comment: I misread your code, but this is the comma op: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you liked the OP or not? :)

Comment: Why shouldn't I?

Comment: This is probably the best answer possible. I'm just miffed that I never thought of iterating over a string like this, and especially in a way that works with a `const` string. Nice answer!

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel idk maybe think about it a little harder

Comment: @MrCholo You sad you can't use template strings maybe you can't use any es6?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel your answer is perfect but there is one thing missing

Comment: Using `%s` as the key?

Comment: Nope, like I said your answer is perfect

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it

Comment: It seems to me as though he had everything you wanted @MrCholo - no idea what you're referring to.

Comment: I created a well-formatted question for which you received 4+ upvotes, common courtesy suggests returning the favor - here is another related question if you want to continue your conquests: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53421730/reduce-nested-array-to-formatted-string

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `replace()` directly with a little fancy closure work to capture the index (which sadly isn't passed to the replace callback function):

```js
const m = 'Map<?,?>';
const types = ['string', 'boolean'];

let rep = m.replace(/\?/g, ((i) => () => types[i++])(0)) // i is simple a count of matches starting at 0
console.log(rep)
```

If the immediately-executed function is too weird, you can wrap the whole thing as a simple function that's a little easier on the eyes:

```js
const m = 'Map<?,?>';
const types = ['string', 'boolean'];

function replaceMatch(str, arr){
    let i = 0
    return str.replace(/\?/g, () => arr[i++])
}

console.log(replaceMatch(m, types))
```

Comment: Interesting answer! That is one _weird_ looking closure

Answer (score 0):

You only need one `?`

```js
const types = ['string', 'boolean'];

console.log('Map<?>'.split('?').join(types))
```

or

```js
const types = ['string', 'boolean'];

console.log('Map<?>'.replace('?', types))
```

or if you wished to keep `?,?`

```js
const types = ['string', 'boolean'];

console.log('Map<?,?>'.replace('?,?', types))
```