# Reduce nested array to formatted string

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to reduce this nested array:

```
const list = ['Map<%s,%s>', ['string', 'Map<%s,%s>', ['string', 'boolean']]];
```

so that list becomes:

```
'Map<string,Map<string,boolean>>'
```

Here is a start, but the recusion is really confusing to me:

```
const util = require('util');

const reduceToString = function(l){
  return l.reduceRight((a,b) => {
    if(Array.isArray(a)){
      return reduceToString(a);
    }

    return util.format(b, a);

  });
};


console.log(reduce(list));
```

*For better understanding to see how this needs to work generically, this input:*

```
const list = ['Map<%s,%s,%s>', ['string', 'Map<%s,%s>', ['string', 'boolean'], 'number']];
```

should yield:

```
'Map<string,Map<string,boolean>,number>'
```

The **general rule** is: any array to the right of a string, should be interpolated into the string, and the reduceToString function should always return a string.

Comment: The nested array seems off; the outermost array's first element has two `%s`, so it should either have three elements total, where the 2nd to last are inserted into the first, or it should have two elements, where the 2nd is an array that has in turn two elements, reflecting the two `%s`. The nested array you have doesn't seem to have a consistent grammar.

Comment: The rule is any array that is to the right of a string, gets interpolated into the string. I double-checked and the example seems fine.

Comment: Are there only `Map` types, or the type is dynamic (could be others)?

Comment: You could do this `list.join('').replace(/%s,%s>/g, '').replace(/<,/g, '<') + '>>'` if your Array format is guaranteed to be always the same.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir there could many types besides Map, it has to be generic etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach can be to "reduce" any element that is an array (going down to the deepest level) and then do your replacements as you keep returning from the stack for any element whose "next element" is an array:

```js
const list = ['Map<%s,%s,%s>', ['string', 'Map<%s,%s>', ['string', 'boolean'], 'Number']];

function merge(list) {
  function reduce(arr) {
    arr = arr.map(e => Array.isArray(e) ? reduce(e) : e);
    return arr
      .map((e, i) => Array.isArray(arr[i + 1])
        ? arr[i + 1].reduce((a, c) => a.replace('%s', c), e)
        : e)
      .filter(e => !Array.isArray(e));
  }
  return reduce(list)[0];
}


console.log(merge(list));
```

Comment: One thing to check is if this works for arrays with length 0 and 1, instead of only length greater than 1

Comment: @MrCholo With length 0, this returns `undefined` and with length 1 it returns the first string in the array (which I think can be considered acceptable behavior).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this recursively with `replace()`:

```js
const list = ['Map<%s,%s,%s>', ['string', 'Map<%s,%s>', ['string', 'boolean'], 'Number']];

function replaceMatch(arr, i=0){
    let str = arr[0]
    return str.replace(/%s/g, () => {
        let next = arr[1]
        if (Array.isArray(next[i+1])) {
            i+=2
            return replaceMatch(next.slice(i-2))       
        }
        else return next[i++]
    })
}
str = replaceMatch(list)
console.log(str)
```

Here's a longer, but probably easier-to-read recursive version. It returns an array rather than a string to allow non-mappings to end up in the result (for example the first and last elements. It will add a `?` if the mapping has more slots than array values and ignore extra array values that don't have corresponding `%s`:

```js
const list = ["Name", 'Map<%s,%s,%s>', ['string', 'Map<%s,%s,%s>', ['string', 'boolean'], 'Number'], 'Set<%s,%s>', ['val_1', 'val_2']];

function replaceArr(str, arr){ // helper function for replace
    let i = 0
    return str.replace(/\%s/g, () => arr[i++] || '?')
}

function replaceMatch(arr){
  let res = []
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++){
      if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) continue
      res.push(Array.isArray(arr[i+1])
          ? replaceArr(arr[i], replaceMatch(arr[i+1]))
          : arr[i]
        )
  }
  return res
}
str = replaceMatch(list)
console.log(str)
```

Comment: Also, good call with your data input, that is more general and accurate than the original input in the OP, thank you (even though no Map I know of has 3 params, maybe change the OP to `Map<?,<?,?>>`, idk

Comment: Yeah, I would like to make the magic number go away…when you are replacing you need to skip over the arrays in the list. That's why I added the extra `%s` because it's easy to miss. If I think of a purer recursive way, I'll edit.

Comment: sure I updated my comment above as well, yeah any number besides 0 or 1 in code is magic right haha, although 3 is even scarier than 2 lulz

Comment: One thing to check is if this works for arrays with length 0 and 1, instead of only length greater than 1.. I checked for length 1, and it returns undefined instead of a placeholder. How about return a question mark ?, if there is no corresponding value in the array?

Comment: I still can't figure out what `i+=2` is doing. The only time you seem to use `i` again is the next line where you subtract 2 from it.

Comment: @MrCholo :) yeah, it's a little hard on the eyes. `i` is used again in `next[i++]`. I posted a different idea that's a little wordier, but probably easier to understand and more flexible.

Comment: I created a solution too, check it out

Comment: That looks pretty nice @MrCholo -- popping from the array is a nice way to handle this.

Comment: thanks I am working on a types generator for JSON. Given some info, can generate the JSON interfaces in any language. The world needs this. When using a command line tool or hitting an API, you would be able to get type information about the JSON coming back. https://github.com/ORESoftware/oredoc

Comment: I need a way to allow the user to express arbitrary nested types. Before the placeholders, I had this `['Array','Array', 'int']` which would be transformed to `Array<Array<int>>` (or a different syntax depending on the language), but that's not generic enough, I needed nestedness.

Answer (score 2):

This was much harder than I thought it would be. This solution returns an array, and is more generic than other solutions and what the OP originally asked for. Since it can handle two strings in a row.

```
const util = require('util');
const list = ['Array','Map<%s,%s, %s>', ['xxx','Map<%s,%s>', ['string', 'boolean'], 'number']];

const reduce = function(list){
  return list.slice(1).reduce((a,b) => {

    if(Array.isArray(b)){
      const pop = a.pop();
      const format = util.format(pop,...reduce(b));
      return a.concat(format);
    }

    return (a.push(b), a);  // comma operator

  },
    [list[0]]
  );
};


console.log(reduce(list));
```

The above will yield:

```
[ 'Array', 'Map<xxx,Map<string,boolean>, number>' ]
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the inner `reduce` helper in the solution I posted. If your final desired output is an array, you can use that directly.

Comment: the best way to understand how this works is to put `console.log({a,b})` inside the Array.prototype reduce callback.